# Exam package: two issues with cover header

Tags: header-footer, exam

When I use the `coverpages` environment (exam package), I get two issues:

1. The cover header doesn't show up in the cover page.
2. The underline on the first page's header is missing.

An MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\title{Some Title}
\author{Danny Mendel}
\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\runningheadrule
\header{Some Course}{Foo}{Bar Baz}
\footer{}{Page \thepage\ of \numpages}{}
\coverlhead{Test}

\begin{document}
\begin{coverpages}
    \maketitle
\end{coverpages}

\begin{questions}
    \question Two test questions.
    \begin{parts}
        \part[3] This is a test question.
        \part[2] This is anoter test question.
    \end{parts}
    
    \newpage
    \question Two more test questions.
    \begin{parts}
        \part[3] This is a test question.
        \part[2] This is anoter test question.
    \end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

I would appreciate any help with the matter.

Comment: On your second point, use `\firstpageheadrule` or use `\headrule` to enable both options.

Answer (score 1):

On your first question: `\maketitle` sets the page style to `plain`, so you have to include the header-and-footer page style:

```
\begin{coverpages}
    \maketitle
    \thispagestyle{headandfoot}
\end{coverpages}
```

On your second question, add `\firstpageheadrule` or use `\headrule`. See Section 11.1 and 11.5 of the `exam` documentation.

Comment: Great, thank you!